# How to assign starting address to an interator of a map<pair<long long int,long long int>,long long int >

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, std-pair

I created a map of a pair and long long int -

```
map< pair< long long int, long long int >,long long int >;
```

and an interator -

```
map< pair< long long int, long long int >, long long int >::iterator it1;
```

and when I did `it1=same.begin()` the compiler is throwing an error, why is this so ?

Error generated:

```
no viable overloaded '=' 
it1=same12.begin();
~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/map:648:29:
>   note: candidate function
>         (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: no known conversion from
>   '__map_iterator<__tree_iterator<__value_type, [...]>, __node_pointer, [...]>>' to 'const __map_iterator<__tree_iterator<__value_type, [...]>,
>         std::__1::__tree_node, long long>, void *> *, [...]>>' for 1st argument
>   class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY __map_iterator

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: error: no viable overloaded '='
        it1=same.begin();
        ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Also, it helps if you didn't type in the code, and actually copy and paste the code you're compiling in your post.  The reason is that this line: `map< pair< long long int, long long int >,long long int > > same` has too many `>` (unless this is the error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error tells you:

> no known conversion from `'__map_iterator<...>'` to `'const __map_iterator<_...>'`

Notice the `const`.

Here, it looks like `same12` is a `const map` (or a `const map&`, or perhaps it's being used inside a `const` method in which case const-correctness is being applied). This means that [`.begin()` will return `const_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/begin), not `iterator`.

You need to change the type of `it1` to a `const_iterator` instead of an `iterator`. The full type should be: `map<pair<long long int, long long int>, long long int>::const_iterator`.

Or just use `auto it1 = same12.begin();`.